# Querying MySQL table using dynamic variables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to Query a MySQL table to to bring any result that matches data that the user has input. The database,table and column names are also dynamically stored in variables. `var_dump` produces a `bool(false)` which means my query is wrong.

**My Code**

```
if (isset ( $_POST ['name'] )) {
            $name = trim ( $_POST ['name'] );
            $tblName = $_REQUEST ['tbl'];
            $colqry = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$dbName' AND TABLE_NAME = '$tblName'";
            echo "<ul>";
            $col_names = mysqli_query ( $link, $colqry );
            while ( $col = mysqli_fetch_array ( $col_names, MYSQL_ASSOC ) ) {
                $colName = $col ['COLUMN_NAME'];
                $tblQry = "SELECT * FROM $tblName WHERE $colName=$name LIMIT 10";
                $query2 = mysqli_query ($link, $tblQry);
                echo $query2;
                while ( $query3 = mysqli_fetch_array ( $query2 ) ) {

                    echo "<li onclick=fill'" . $query3 [0] . "'>" . $query3 [0] . "</li>";
                }
            }
        }
```

What I want to achieve is list a table where the search terms matches something on the table either the column name or the data inside the columns

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($link))` to `mysqli_query()`. You'll see errors in your query.

Comment: `WHERE '$colName'='%$name%'` you're looking to use `LIKE` when using `%` signs. I.e.: `WHERE '$colName' LIKE '%$name%'`. Otherwise, do `WHERE '$colName'='$name'` for an exact match.

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor design!

Comment: If i use `LIKE` it will list all the data in that column, but I want to specific data in the column not the actual column name.

Comment: You're quoting the table and column names as if they were strings, e.g. `SELECT * FROM '$tblName' WHERE '$colName'='%$name%'`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html - You're using incorrect identifiers. `mysqli_error($link)` would have thrown you an error in `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: A good way of troubleshooting this sort of programmatically generated query is to echo or display it right before you run it. I suspect, if you do that, you'll see your mistake.

Comment: Fixed this after I had posted the OP, however I still can't search the table data as opposed to finding a column_name.

Comment: Have you used what I suggested in [my first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121317/querying-mysql-table-using-dynamic-variables#comment46469179_29121317)? Plus, do a `var_dump();` to see what's going through or not. Your form also has a POST method, right? If not, forms default to GET if omitted and will fail *silently*.

Comment: We also don't see where you've assigned `$dbName` and this `MYSQL_ASSOC` should be `MYSQLI_ASSOC`. You're mixing APIs.

Comment: I already have a `die(mysqli_error($link))` for my connection further up the code. I am sure that the connection isnt an issue since if I rectify the query and search a valid column name it will list the results. However I want to search table content as opposed to the `column_names`. How do I achieve this??

Comment: It's not the connection that I asked you to check, it's your query. I've already outlined that in the/my first comment.

Comment: The query is fine, I've updated the OP with the correct syntax, Results are listed but only if I search a valid column_name , I want to search by column content as opposed to the column header. If I search by content I get a `mysqli_fetch_array` error boolean given

Comment: Well this `MYSQL_ASSOC` is still incorrect, it's `MYSQLI_ASSOC` and `WHERE $colName=$name` you're missing quotes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73247/discussion-between-noobatnerd-and-fred-ii).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$tblQry = "SELECT * FROM $tblName WHERE $colName=$name LIMIT 10";
```

Quote the `$name` variable:

so it reads as `WHERE $colName='$name'`

You can then use `$query3[$colname]` to get the search match you're looking for.

For more information on identifer qualifiers, visit:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html